# Previous button not working for DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

How can I fix the previous button to move backward in dataGridView row?
The next button is working.
It does nothing.
I don't know how to fix that. Any ideas? I  would appreciate it.

Here is my code:

```
int nRow;

private void Form1_Load
{
    nRow = DataGridView2.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
}

private void PreviousData_Click
{
    if (row>=0)
    {
        if (row!=0)
        {
            DataGridView2.Rows[row].Selected = false;
            DataGridView2.Rows[--row].Selected = true;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Need More Data!");
        }
    }
}

int row;

private void DataGridView2_CellClick
{
    if (DataGridView2.SelectedRows.Count != -1)
    {
        row = DataGridView2.CurrentRow.Index;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just step through the code and debug it???

Comment: That doesn't look like a button click event handler to me. How did you bind the event to the click? In code or via the designer? Thanks

Comment: @Wheels73 nothing in this code is even compilable

Comment: @Chris - Suggest you revise the post into compilable code. And if you have your Next button working, which you've not posted, just do the same for your previous button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the following two events to your `previous` and `next` buttons, respectively and it will do the job.

```
private void PreviousData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var currentRow = DataGridView2.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

    if (currentRow == 0)
        return;
    else
        currentRow--;

    DataGridView2.ClearSelection();
    DataGridView2.CurrentCell = DataGridView2.Rows[currentRow].Cells[0];
    DataGridView2.Rows[currentRow].Selected = true;
}

private void NextData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var currentRow = DataGridView2.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

    if (currentRow == DataGridView2.RowCount - 1)
        return;
    else
        currentRow++;

    DataGridView2.ClearSelection();
    DataGridView2.CurrentCell = DataGridView2.Rows[currentRow].Cells[0];
    DataGridView2.Rows[currentRow].Selected = true;
}
```

Comment: Working well! What should I modify to get the last row for click?

Comment: @Chris What you mean by  `get the last row for click`?

Comment: Like, jumping to the last inserted row

Comment: I have modified a bit and working well :)


`int currentRow = DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1;
                DataGridView2.ClearSelection();
                DataGridView2.CurrentCell = DataGridView2.Rows[currentRow].Cells[0];
                DataGridView2.Rows[currentRow].Selected = true;`